# Mount the second partition of an image with hdiutil

Tags: macos, partitioning, filesystems, mount, hdiutil

I'm trying to open a partition on my Mac (OSX Mavericks).
Particularly, I've got a `file.img` image which includes two partitions: a boot partition and a second partition formatted in ext2.
When I launch the command `hdiutil mount file.img` it only loads the first partition, although I can read ext2 filesystems (osx-fuse + fuse-ext2 are installed and I can read ext2 file systems on physical drives).
I also tried from the Disk Utility software: I see the second partition into my image file, but I can't mount it.

How can I mount both the partitions, especially the second/ext2 one?